# Nosetests giving "Improperly Configured" Error

Tags: python, django, django-nose

I'm learning to use django-nose but I'm having trouble setting it up.

`./manage.py test` works just fine. But `nosetests` doesn't.

I've added `django_nose` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and set `TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'`. Still it's raising `ImproperlyConfigured`.

I tried googling but either this is not a common problem or I've been using the wrong queries. No luck there.

```
$ nosetests

EE
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImproperlyConfigured (Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 413, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/<path/to/app>/tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.test import TestCase
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.test.client import Client, RequestFactory
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, get_user_model
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import get_cache
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: Did you try running `python manage.py test`?

Comment: Yes - "`./manage.py test` works just fine."

Comment: interestingly, first line of output from `python manage.py test` is `nosetests --verbosity=1`.

Comment: Because you've told Django to use nose as its test runner. When you run `nosetests` directly, you are bypassing Django. `manage.py test` is the correct way to integrate the two.

Comment: I didn't realize I wasn't supposed to run `nosetests` directly... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@dirn answered the question but left it as a comment..

I wasn't supposed to run `nosetests` directly, but should use `python manage.py test` and have python invoke nose for me instead.